# Google Sheets Converting numbers imported from a different country, switching commas with periods

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regexp-replace

I'm importing numbers represented with commas instead of dots, and dots instead of commas, in Google sheets, and I need to convert them: from

```
32.072,25 to 32072.25
-1,06     to -1.06
```

For now I'm doing it with two nested RegExReplace expressions

```
REGEXREPLACE( REGEXREPLACE( B2, "\.","" ), 
              ",", "\." )
```

I believe that it could be done without nesting, as part of the same RegEx operation, but I'm not knowledgeable enough about the RegEx syntax and logic to find a way. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(""&B2, "[.]"), 
 SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2, ".", ), ",", "."), SUBSTITUTE(B2, ",", "."))
```

to get numeric values:

```
=1*IF(REGEXMATCH(""&B2, "[.]"), 
 SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2, ".", ), ",", "."), SUBSTITUTE(B2, ",", "."))
```

Comment: Both formulas give numeric values, thanks!